# JGit - Push a specific file to RemoteRepo

Tags: git, egit, jgit

What I have done till now is -

1. Cloned from Remote Repo.
2. Added a file to specific directory in my project and made some changes in that file
3. Committed the file
4. Trying to push the changes to Remote Repo
    // it's showing me message a null and status as OK but **the file isn't getting pushed to the Remote Repo**.

   Another Problem is when I am trying to print push message it's infinitely printing - **Msg- null - Status - OK - refs/heads/master**

---

```java
private static final String REMOTE_URL = "http://abc.def.net/git/scm/nt/myprojectname.git"

String srcPath = "D://MyFiles//fol//ErrorFile.txt";

// prepare a new folder for the cloned repository
File localPath = File.createTempFile("TestGitRepository", "");
localPath.delete();

// then clone
System.out.println("Cloning from " + REMOTE_URL + " to " + localPath);
CredentialsProvider cp = new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider("myUserName","mypassword");

Git git = Git.cloneRepository().setURI(REMOTE_URL).setDirectory(localPath).setCredentialsProvider(cp).call();

String head = git.getRepository().getFullBranch();
if (head.startsWith("refs/heads/")) {
        // Print branch name with "refs/heads/" stripped.
        System.out.println("Current branch is " + git.getRepository().getBranch());
}

String destPath = localPath+"\\myprojectName\\" ;
File srcFile = new File(srcPath);
File destFile = new File(destPath);
FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(srcFile, destFile, true) ;

git.checkout(); // MISSED THIS LINE EARLIER

// run the add-call
git.add().setUpdate(true).addFilepattern(destFile.getAbsolutePath()).call();

RevCommit revCommit = git.commit().setMessage("My First Commit").call();
System.out.println(revCommit.getShortMessage() );
Iterable<PushResult> resultIterable = git.push().setCredentialsProvider(cp).call();

while(resultIterable.iterator().hasNext()){               // LEADING TO INFINITE LOOP
PushResult result = resultIterable.iterator().next();
Collection<RemoteRefUpdate> rs = result.getRemoteUpdates();
  for(RemoteRefUpdate rf : rs){
    System.out.println("Msg- "+rf.getMessage() + " - Status - "+rf.getStatus() + " - "+rf.getSrcRef());
  }
}

try {
  System.out.println("Having repository: " + git.getRepository().getDirectory());
} finally {
  git.getRepository().close();
}
```

Comment: Check your gitignore. Is the file or one of its ancestor folders there?

Comment: With Git you don't push files, you push commits. How did you determine that the commit you just created never ended up in the destination git?

Comment: @MagnusBäck, you can push files as well, in the sense that you are creating a file, add it, commit it and push it.

Comment: yes... i hv added the file, then committed it and then performed PUSH ... but when I cloned again.. that file is not present in the new clone. Meaning the file hasn't been pushed.

Comment: Ohh.. I missed git.checkout(); before git.commit();  now .. the file is being added. The Only problem remaining is - why there is infinite loop when I am trying to print push results == System.out.println("Msg- "+rf.getMessage() + " - Status - "+rf.getStatus() + " - "+rf.getSrcRef());

Comment: @br001, checkout is needed, but, what do you mean by "infinite loop"? What do you see exactly?

Comment: @LajosArpad when I run the above prog. It keeps on printing :   Msg- null - Status - OK - refs/heads/master

Comment: @br001, can you edit your question with your latest code and specify where the problem happens?

Comment: @LajosArpad I have edited my code i.e. I have inserted a line with git.checkout(); before committing the file. Now It's pushing my changes(commits) well, but when I am trying to print the response message of git.push() , it keeps on printing :-  Msg- null - Status - OK - refs/heads/master

Answer (score 0):

Your file is not commited, because you need to specify which files you want to commit. In your case

```
git.commit().setAll(true)
```

should work, its equivalent of git commit -a

I also got this working -

```
CommitCommand commit = git.commit();
for (String file : files) {
    commit.setOnly(file);
}
commit.setMessage(message).call()
```